# laravel get model vuejs data false

Tags: laravel, vue.js

with vue js axios i am sending get request with id from routes and using **"show" function**
I'm trying to fetch the data that matches the `account_id` in the `"account_id"` column of the **"transactions" table** with the id of 5 and the id of the **"accounts" table**. The incoming data looks correct, but when I want to show the data in the vuejs component, the data returns empty to me.
I couldn't figure out where the error is.

```
localhost/transactions/5
```

Route

```
Route::prefix('transactions')->group(function () {
    Route::get('{id}', [AccountsController::class, 'show']);
});
```

AccountsController

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $show = Transaction::where('id', $id)->with(['account'])->first();
        return response()->json($show);
    }
```

Transaction Model

```
public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class);
    }
```

**"transaction type" data value false from v-if is written.**

vue component

```
<template>
<div>
<p>{{data.attributes.transaction_type}}</p>
<div v-if="data.attributes.transaction_type =! 'sales'">
<p>Salesss</p>
</div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            id: this.$route.params.id,
            data: {
                type: "transactions",
                attributes: {},
            },
        }
    },
    async created() {
        const res = await this.callApi('get', this.data.type + '/' + this.id)
        if (res.status === 200) {
            this.data.attributes = res.data;
            console.log(res.data)
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: does network send data correctly ?

Comment: I found the source of the error but I don't know the solution I'm editing the question. sourced from vue component

Comment: cool. so does network send the data . please check it via network

Comment: There is no problem with the data coming from the network. Because I wrote if in component. changing the value